# Using pip in pythonbrew

Tags: python, pip, pythonbrew

I have started using pythonbrew to manage different Python installs.  The main reason I wanted to do this is to install third party modules without affecting my system's Python install.

Fore example I thought I would install the `requests` library using:

`pip install requests`

However this causes an error saying:

`error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests': Permission denied`

Obviously I don't want to install it to the system's Python which is Python 2.7.3.  I did have to install pip with my package manager and the resultant path is `/usr/bin/pip`.

How can I use pip to install to my pythonbrew installs?  (My current pythonbrew Python version is 3.3.0) Am I missing something?

Comment: have you run "pythonbrew switch 3.3.0" for your session before running "pip install requests"?

Comment: @JayAtkinson Yes, I have.  `python -V` prints Python 3.3.0. :)

Comment: Normally when I use pip it's used with the pythonbrew installed version of Python. I wonder if that may be the problem or if you PYTHONBREWHOME is not setup properly.  I don't normally us a pip located in /usr/bin/pip.

Comment: @JayAtkinson I thought it came packaged with pythonbrew like you said.  I thought the pip install would be my home directory somewhere.

Comment: I have seen issues where something failed to compile in the installation of a Python Version from pythonbrew that can kill the rest of the install process and "pip" doesn't get installed in the pythonbrew python version.  You may want to check  your build log inside ".pythonbrew" directory.

Comment: @JayAtkinson Nothing alarming in the log. I did a `grep -i` for pip and fail and there wasn't anything out of normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.  I uninstalled my Python 3.3.0 by issuing `pythonbrew uninstall 3.3.0`.  Then I installed it again with `pythonbrew install --configure="--with-zlib" 3.3.0`.  This allowed `pip` to install and thus now I can use it to install to this Python version.

Maybe somebody else can find this helpful, cheers!